# Exception when adding Dictionary entry

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, dictionary

We're seeing this exception occur in the following block of code in an ASP.NET context which is running on an IIS 7 server.

```
1) Exception Information
*********************************************  
Exception Type: System.Exception  
Message: Exception Caught in Application_Error event
Error in: InitializationStatus.aspx  
Error Message:An item with the same key has already been added.  
Stack Trace:    at
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)   
at CredentialsSession.GetXmlSerializer(Type serializerType)
```

This is the code that the exception is occuring in:

```
[Serializable()]
public class CredentialsSession
{
    private static Dictionary<string, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer> localSerializers = new Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>();

    private System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer GetXmlSerializer(Type serializerType)
    {
        string sessionObjectName = serializerType.ToString() + ".Serializer";

        if (Monitor.TryEnter(this))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!localSerializers.ContainsKey(sessionObjectName))
                {
                    localSerializers.Add(sessionObjectName, CreateSerializer(serializerType));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(this);
            }
        }
        return localSerializers[sessionObjectName];
    }

    private System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer CreateSerializer(Type serializerType)
    {
        XmlAttributes xmlAttributes = GetXmlOverrides();

        XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(ElementBase), "Elements", xmlAttributes);

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(serializerType, xmlOverrides);

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

The **Monitor.TryEnter** should be preventing multiple threads from entering the block simultaneously, and the code is checking the Dictionary to verify that it does not contain the key that is being added.

Any ideas on how this could happen?

Comment: +1, for the question which explains how to find a duplicate in Dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe.

1. You're locking on `this`, a `CredentialsSession` instance, but accessing a static dictionary which can be shared by multiple `CredentialsSession` instances.  This explains why you're getting the error - two different `CredentialsSession` instances are attempting to write to the dictionary concurrently.
2. Even if you change this to lock on a static field as suggested in @sll's answer, you aren't thread-safe, because you aren't locking when reading the dictionary.  You need a `ReaderWriterLock` or `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to efficiently allow multiple readers and a single writer.

   Therefore you should probably use a thread-safe dictionary.  `ConcurrentDictionary` as others have said if you're using .NET 4.0.  If not you should implement your own, or use an existing implementation such as http://devplanet.com/blogs/brianr/archive/2008/09/26/thread-safe-dictionary-in-net.aspx.

Your comments suggest you want to avoid calling `CreateSerializer` for the same type multiple times.  I don't know why, because the performance benefit is likely to be negligible, since contention is likely to be rare and can't exceed once for each type during the lifetime of the application.

But if you really want this, you can do it as follows:

```
var value;
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    lock(dictionary)
    {
        if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value = CreateSerializer(...);
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

From comment:

> if I implement this with ConcurrentDictionary and simply call TryAdd(sessionObjectName, CreateSerializer(serializerType)) every time.

The answer is not to call TryAdd every time - first check if it's in the dictionary, then add if it isn't.  A better alternative might be to use [the `GetOrAdd` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx) that takes a `Func` argument.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the Dictionary is static!  That explains a lot, thanks!  I am re-implementing this with ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Assuming GetXmlSerializer gets called frequently to retrieve values from the Dictionary, if I implement this with ConcurrentDictionary and simply call TryAdd(sessionObjectName, CreateSerializer(serializerType)) every time, then CreateSerializer will be called each time GetXmlSerializer is called.  It seems like I would want to avoid this.  Once the dictionary is populated for each key value, there  isn't a reason to call CreateSerializer any more.  Correct?

Comment: +1 since this answer fully describes existing problem and suggesting how to solve it for different cases

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it described the nature of the existing problem.  The other answers were also very helpful in resolving this issue.  I ended up implementing this with a ConcurrentDictionary and used its AddOrUpdate method as suggested by  Fredrik Mörk.

Comment: Correction:  I actually implemented this with the GetOrAdd method.

Answer (score 5):

Try out locking on `localSerializers` rather that `this`. BTW, why you are using Monitor explicitly? Only one reason I see is to provide [lock timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbdx9xx.aspx) which obviously you are not using, so use simply [lock() statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead this would generate try/finally as well:

```
lock (localSerializers)
{
   if (!localSerializers.ContainsKey(sessionObjectName))                 
   {                     
      localSerializers.Add(
            sessionObjectName, 
            CreateSerializer(serializerType));                 
   } 
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Since you've not specified in tags that you're using .NET 4 I would suggest using
`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`

---

[Monitor.Enter() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx):

> Use a C# try…finally block (Try…Finally in Visual Basic) to ensure
>   that you release the monitor, or use the C# lock statement (SyncLock
>   statement in Visual Basic), which wraps the Enter and Exit methods in
>   a try…finally block

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Not originally my code, so I can't provide an answer for why it is using Monitor explicitly.  It makes perfect sense to lock the resource that is being protected rather than this.  I will try this, thanks!

Comment: @Avalanchis : see EDIT part of updated answer, also I've added .NET 4 tag for your question, it is pretty important

Comment: I like the idea of using ConcurrentDictionary, but I'm concerned about unnecessary calls to CreateSerializer.  It seems that I still need to call ContainsKey to see if the key exists prior to calling TryAdd if I want to avoid calling CreateSerializer every time.  Correct?

Comment: Perhaps I could use GetOrAdd and provide a valueFactory argument to generate the value?

Comment: yes, you are right, for your case when you need to return serializer it is better to check whether it exists and then just request it from a dictionary and return. So just use Containskey() because before executing `GetOrAdd()` `CreateSerializer()` would be called anyway checking for a key existance

Comment: locking on localSerializers is still not thread-safe.  A ConcurrentDictionary is the way to go for .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Joe : yes I see your question, it describes full picture of the current problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET Framework 4 or later, I would suggest that you use a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead. The `TryAdd` method keeps you safe from this kind of scenario, without the need to litter your code with locks:

```
localSerializers.TryAdd(sessionObjectName, CreateSerializer(serializerType))
```

If you are worried about `CreateSerializer` to be invoked when it's not needed, you should instead use `AddOrUpdate`:

```
localSerializers.AddOrUpdate(
    sessionObjectName,
    key => CreateSerialzer(serializerType),
    (key, value) => value);
```

This will ensure that the method is called only when you need to produce a new value (when it needs to be added to the dictionary). If it's already present, the entry will be "updated" with the already existing value.

Comment: We are using .NET 4.  Would it still make sense to check to see if the ConcurrentDictionary contains the key to be added first?  I'm concerned that TryAdd might unnecessarily call CreateSerializer if the key already exists.